# do downvotes on meta indicate disagreement with the question's premise

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, meta

I read the comments on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112246/minimum-number-of-characters-to-change-is-problematic) question and somehow stumbled over this comment:

> Downvotes on meta indicate disagreement with the question's premise,
>       not that you asked a bad question.

as it indicates that if you want to get some reputation (which is for example needed for mod-elections) you actually have to ask questions that are not individual, and maybe controversy but, those which represent the masses opinion and this completely contradicts my opinion of a valuable question, especially if discussions (and therefore different opinions) are ok.

Now I am wondering if this comment can be applied on most meta-users or is just a single opinion.

Comment: As it says in the linked [faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work) - *This isn't an official rule, but it has become the de facto accepted community standard.* You can gain reputation by several means: helping newbies with support issues, finding bugs in the system and mostly taking active part in discussions, where the most votes are cast, mostly when discussing major feature requests.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/272617/1159478) is a much better explanation of voting than the linked duplicate.